# Could not deduce Enum a from arithmetic sequence

Tags: list, haskell, enums

I am new to Haskell and ran into an error I couldn't resolve while trying to compile this code (part of calculating a determinant):

```
--pivotzeile = 1
--pivotspalte 0 based!
genLaplaceMatrix :: (Num a, Enum a, Num b, Ord b) => [[a]] -> b -> [[a]]
genLaplaceMatrix [[]] _ = error "Cannot calculate LaplaceMatrix from [[]]"
genLaplaceMatrix x pivotSpalte 
    | pivotSpalte < 0                         = error "invalid column"
    | pivotSpalte > ((genericLength x) -1)    = error "invalid column"
    | otherwise                       = foldr (\y acc -> (conVecs y):acc ) [0..((genericLength x)-1)] []
    where
      leftPart = take pivotSpalte
      rightPart lP z = takeRight (leftPart lP) z
      conVecs col = concatVectors (leftPart x!!col) (rightPart (leftPart x!!col) (x!!col) )
```

The Error is the following:

```
main.hs:29:76: error:
    • Could not deduce (Enum [a])
        arising from the arithmetic sequence ‘0 .. ((genericLength x) - 1)’
      from the context: (Num a, Enum a, Num b, Ord b)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   genLaplaceMatrix :: (Num a, Enum a, Num b, Ord b) =>
                                       [[a]] -> b -> [[a]]
        at main.hs:24:1-72
    • In the second argument of ‘foldr’, namely
        ‘[0 .. ((genericLength x) - 1)]’
      In the expression:
        foldr
          (\ y acc -> (conVecs y) : acc) [0 .. ((genericLength x) - 1)] []
      In an equation for ‘genLaplaceMatrix’:
          genLaplaceMatrix x pivotSpalte
            | pivotSpalte < 0 = error "invalid column"
            | pivotSpalte > ((genericLength x) - 1) = error "invalid column"
            | otherwise
            = foldr
                (\ y acc -> (conVecs y) : acc) [0 .. ((genericLength x) - 1)] []
            where
                leftPart = take pivotSpalte
                rightPart lP z = takeRight (leftPart lP) z
                conVecs col
                  = concatVectors
                      (leftPart x !! col) (rightPart (leftPart x !! col) (x !! col))
main.hs:29:77: error:
    • Could not deduce (Num [a]) arising from the literal ‘0’
      from the context: (Num a, Enum a, Num b, Ord b)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   genLaplaceMatrix :: (Num a, Enum a, Num b, Ord b) =>
                                       [[a]] -> b -> [[a]]
        at main.hs:24:1-72
    • In the expression: 0
      In the second argument of ‘foldr’, namely
        ‘[0 .. ((genericLength x) - 1)]’
      In the expression:
        foldr
          (\ y acc -> (conVecs y) : acc) [0 .. ((genericLength x) - 1)] []
```

At first I didn't have The `Enum a` in the definition, did a little research and then tried to add the enum in various ways. Sadly none of them worked.

It tells me that the error arises upon the creation of the first list for the foldr. But what is wrong there?

The full code can be found at [repl.it](https://repl.it/@faebl/DramaticAppropriateGossamerwingedbutterfly)

UPDATE: 
Second Error:

```
main.hs:31:23: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘b’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          genLaplaceMatrix :: forall a b.
                              (Num a, Enum a, Num b, Ord b) =>
                              [[a]] -> b -> [[a]]
        at main.hs:24:21
    • In the first argument of ‘take’, namely ‘pivotSpalte’
      In the expression: take pivotSpalte
      In an equation for ‘leftPart’: leftPart = take pivotSpalte
    • Relevant bindings include
        pivotSpalte :: b (bound at main.hs:26:20)
        genLaplaceMatrix :: [[a]] -> b -> [[a]] (bound at main.hs:25:1)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: (I recently asked a similar question, but deleted it because the question wasn't formulated properly and the discussion got off topic.)

Comment: Please don't delete questions. Formatting can be fixed.

Comment: I will keep that in mind the next time; but the question also changed a bit that's why i thought it might be better to open up a new topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to swap the arguments of the `foldr` call, so:

```
foldr (\y acc -> (conVecs y):acc ) [0..((genericLength x)-1)] []
```

to:

```
foldr (\y -> (conVecs y:)) [] [0..genericLength x-1]
```

(some extra modifications)

The reason you get the error is because as outcome, of `foldr`, you expect an `[[a]]`. As a result, Haskell has the idea that `[0..genericLength x-1]` should have type `[[a]]` as well. Since internally it has an `<expr>..<expr>` structure, it then derives that `0` and `genericLength x-1` should have type `[a]`, but it does not know how to enumerate that. Nevertheless, all the above reasoning is based on wrong arguments passed to `foldr`.

I also do not think we need a `genericLength` here at all. We can use `length` with `Int` I guess, so:

```
--pivotzeile = 1
--pivotspalte 0 based!
genLaplaceMatrix :: (Num a, Enum a) => [[a]] -> Int -> [[a]]
genLaplaceMatrix [[]] _ = error "Cannot calculate LaplaceMatrix from [[]]"
genLaplaceMatrix x pivotSpalte 
    | pivotSpalte < 0                         = error "invalid column"
    | pivotSpalte > ((genericLength x) -1)    = error "invalid column"
    | otherwise                       = foldr (\y -> (conVecs y:)) [] [0..length x-1]
    where
      leftPart = take pivotSpalte
      rightPart lP z = takeRight (leftPart lP) z
      conVecs col = concatVectors (leftPart x!!col) (rightPart (leftPart x!!col) (x!!col) )
```

We then obtain:

```
> print $ det [[1,2],[3,4]]
-2
```

which is (given you calculate the determinant) the correct answer.

Comment: @FabianSchneider: why do you use `genericLength` anyway? An `Int` will have a minimum range of -2^29 to +2^29, which seems enough.

Comment: I resolved the second error myself by using [[a]] -> Int -> [[a]] in the declaration. 
Thanks very much :D